# C - appending a row to a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

Is it possible to append a row/column to a matrix in C without for loops? I am having a matrix  float A[4][4] and would like to append a float vector to it  b[1][4] so that I would obtain M = [A; b] - b being the last row - is it doable in C?

Answer (score 1):

No, size of an array depends on its type and automatic objects cannot change their type during their lifetime.

However, the situation is different for dynamic array. If the array was allocated as a sequence of `float[4]` 1d arrays i.e. with:

```
float (*A)[4] = malloc(4 * sizeof *A);
```

then a new **row** can be extended with `realloc()`:

```
A = realloc(A, 5 * sizeof *A);
```

Usually you should check if the reallocation succeeded. If it fails the pointer `A` would be overwritten leading to a memory leak. Therefore the better code would be:

```
float (*newA)[4] = realloc(A, 5 * sizeof *A);
if (!newA) { ... handle error ... }
A = newA;
```